# VS Code - Is there a way to diff compare file contents with sql object definition?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-code, diff

I use Visual Studio Code with the MSSQL extension to do a lot of my work with SQL code.  There are times when I'd like to compare a SQL object definition (ie. of a stored procedure) with what I have in my source control file for that procedure.  I know there are VSCode extensions that allow you to diff two files, but is there any way of diffing a file with a database object definition?

Comment: Schema compare is a feature of Visual Studio and SSDT, not Visual Studio Code. Yet

Answer (score 2):

This feature is now also available in [Azure Data Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/sql/azure-data-studio/download-azure-data-studio?view=sql-server-ver16) using the [Schema Compare extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/extensions/schema-compare-extension?view=sql-server-ver16). Unfortunately it's still not available in Visual Studio Code.

There is an issue on Github to track adding this feature to vscode's mssql extension: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-mssql/issues/1053

Answer (score 1):

In visual studio there is a "Database Project". Once you have the project up and running you can right click on the project and compare it with an entire database.

I think the easiest would be to make it so the database project becomes what you have in source control.